# MVC3- Radion Button Grouping and Binding from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to get the radio button options from database using in MVC3 Razor. I have 4 options for each question, the options should be populated from the database and should be grouped.

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.AAAa, 'Y', new { title = "Please check this if AAA has been updated" })
                Yes
```

This gives me hard coded value as Yes but text  needs to be populated with DB Table.

How would I bind it back the selected value back to the database?. An Example would be more helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always you start by defining a view model that will represent the information you will be dealing with in the view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    // In your question you seem to be dealing with a title attribute as well
    // If this is the case you could define a custom view model ItemViewModel
    // which will contain the Value, the Text and the Title properties for
    // each radio button because the built-in SelectListItem class that I am using here
    // has only Value and Text properties
    public SelectListItem[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

then you write a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            // Obviously those will come from your database or something
            Items = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Y", Text = "Yes" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "N", Text = "No" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "D", Text = "Dunno" }
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

then a corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items[i].Value, new { id = "item_" + i })
        @Html.Label("item_" + i, Model.Items[i].Text)
        <br/>
    }
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

or to make the view less messy you could write a custom HTML helper that will render those radio buttons for you:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items
    )
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var id = string.Format("item{0}", i++);
            var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id });
            var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, item.Text);
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}<br/>", radio, label);
        }

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

and now your view will simply become:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

which obviously is nicer to look.